Switching between Public and Private profiles
I'm working on a group project in which a user can create two types of accounts, a public and a private. If the user creates a public account, his/her private account will also be created and if he creates a private account, then only the private account will be created.
Keeping in mind that I'm creating two collections in Firebase, "publicAccounts" and "privateAccounts".
Now the issue is if the user wants to switch from public account to the private account which also has the exact same "id" in a different collection, then how user will switch between his public and private profiles/accounts through same login id ??
Here's what I'm trying to do, but it again logs in to the user of same collection (privateData collection).
void SwitchAccount() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final User? _user = _auth.currentUser;

    if (_user != null) {
      final String _userId = _user.phoneNumber ?? _user.email ?? "";

      // Log out the current user from Citizens collection
      await _auth.signOut();

      // Log in with the same ID but in the context of publicData collection
      DocumentSnapshot pubDoc =
      await _firestore.collection("publicData").doc(_userId).get();

      if (lawyerDoc.exists) {
        UserCredential? userCredential = await loginWithGoogle();
        if (userCredential != null) {
          Utils().Message("Switching to Public Profile.");
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => home_screen()));
        } else {
          Utils().Message("Login to professional profile failed.");
        }
      } else {
        Utils().Message("No Public Account Registered on current ID.");
      }
    }
  }

  Future<UserCredential?> loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) {
        return null; // The user canceled the sign-in
      }

      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final cred = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      );

      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(cred);
    } catch (e) {
      Utils().Message(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }


It's not clear what your question is asking: "How will they be logged in?"  Please edit the question to clarify what about your code doesn't work the way you expect so we can identify a clear answer to your question.

I'm creating two collections in Firebase, "publicAccounts" and "privateAccounts" I expect a single collection with the accounts, and a flag on each whether the account is public or not. Why do you feel the need to have two separate collections.

"Why do you feel the need to have two separate collections" coz when the User wanted to create a Public then a query will be sent to the admin and if that query is accepted by the admin only then the user can use the publicAccount until the query is pending with the admin, user can use the Private account with limited functionalities.
